# How to get the last 2 digits of a number (integer or decimal)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to get the last 2 digits of integers and decimals.

I'm using `number%100` operator to get the last 2 digits of an integer. However, I get an error when I try the same on a decimal.

Is there any simple way to do it, without converting to a string and parsing?

Example:

```
number = 1234.56789
```

I need to get 89.

```
56789 % 100 = 89
```

`1234.56789 % 100` gives error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

More examples:

```
number = 0.1
```

I need to get `0.1` (with the decimal).

Comment: Hmmm... by "last two digits" do you mean that the last 2 digits of 1013.145 would be 13? Or 45?

Comment: Do you know how many digits beyond the decimal the number will have? Or perhaps a maximum beyond the decimal?

Comment: What would be last two digits in case when number is [`0.1 + 0.2`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)? _(Note: expression is a link)._ Will it be `30` or `04`?

Comment: I think @Rogalski is asking about the issue of [Floating Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). `0.1 + 0.2` will actually return `0.30000000000000004`. Would you want 0.3 or 04 from that?

Comment: @s.py I just want to point-out some non-trivialities about this task, actual "last two" significant digits in floating-point number may differ significantly from intuitive "obviously-it-should-be-x-why-should-it-be-different" approach.

Comment: I would want 0.3 in that case.  The number will be rounded first.  Then the last 2 digits extracted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a working solution to your problem:

```
def last_2_digits_at_best(n):
    return float(str(n)[-3:]) if '.' in str(n)[-2:] else int(str(n)[-2:])

print last_2_digits_at_best(1234.56789)
print last_2_digits_at_best(123)
print last_2_digits_at_best(0.1)
print last_2_digits_at_best(1)
print last_2_digits_at_best(0.1 + 0.2)
```

Output:

```
89
23
0.1
1
0.3
4.5
1.4
```

Comment: Yes, this works. This IS the right answer. Deleting mine as soon as yours is marked as correct answer as I cannot until the OP changes his vote.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in a little different way, may be helpful.

```
# Finding last two digits of a number whether decimal or integer

def number(num):
    if type(num) == float:
        last_two_digit = str(num)[-2:]  # If float, make it string and cut last two digit
        return int(last_two_digit)   # convert back into integer and then return
    else:
        last_two_digit = num%100  # If integer, find the mode by 100
        return last_two_digit 
    
number(45.6912)
# Ans : 12

number(12548)
# Ans : 48
```